# Entity Framework - I'm having trouble editing a complex Entity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Insert is working well. The update is not working for the collections. And do not give any error. What am I doing wrong?
In the code there is a brief explanation of the rules.

```
      public void EditaModelo(Modelo model)
            {
                try
                {
                    // ProjectResponsible - is an unmapped property. It was used to separate ModeloFuncao between type 2 and type 1 (ProjectResponsible and ProductDevelopment)
                    // ModeloFuncao is a collection within a model where for each function there is a responsibility within the model.
                    // In other words, for each record in the function table shows a field on the screen. The same goes for ProductDevelopment.
                    // When you save the model, there will be incusões, deletions and changes of those responsible.
                    // The IsUpdate property tells whether the record already exists and will be changed.
                    var ModelosToAdd = model.ProjectResponsible.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && !x.IsUpdate).ToList();
                    List<ModeloFuncao> ModelosToRemove = model.ProjectResponsible.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && x.IsUpdate).ToList();
                    List<ModeloFuncao> ModelosToUpdate = model.ProjectResponsible.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && x.IsUpdate).ToList();

                    ModelosToAdd.AddRange(model.ProductDevelopment.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && !x.IsUpdate).ToList()); 
                    ModelosToRemove.AddRange(model.ProductDevelopment.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && x.IsUpdate).ToList());
                    ModelosToUpdate.AddRange(model.ProductDevelopment.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Usuario) && x.IsUpdate).ToList());

                    if(ModelosToAdd.Count > 0) context.ModelosFuncoes.AddRange(ModelosToAdd); //Insert is Ok
                    if (ModelosToRemove.Count > 0) context.ModelosFuncoes.RemoveRange(ModelosToRemove); //Not tested
                    if (ModelosToUpdate.Count > 0) ModelosToUpdate.ForEach(x => context.ModelosFuncoes.Attach(x)); //Not working

                    // The ModeloPlanta is a collection in the model table and follow the rules as explained below in ModeloPlantaArea.
                    List<ModeloPlanta> plantasToUpdate = model.ModelosPlantas.ToList();
                    plantasToUpdate.ForEach(x => context.ModelosPlantas.Attach(x));//Not working

            // The ModeloPlantaArea is a collection in the model table. Each model has a number of plants and each plant has a number of areas.
           // Each plant has a responsibility and each area has a responsibility.
           // The screen should display a field for each plant x Responsible  and for each Area x Responsible
           // When you save the model, there will be incusões, deletions and changes of those responsible.
                    List<ModeloPlantaArea> AreasToAdd = model.PlantasArea.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.UsuarioResponsavel) && !x.IsUpdate).ToList();
                    List<ModeloPlantaArea> AreasToUpdate = model.PlantasArea.Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.UsuarioResponsavel) && x.IsUpdate).ToList();
                    List<ModeloPlantaArea> AreasToRemove = model.PlantasArea.Where(x => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.UsuarioResponsavel) && x.IsUpdate).ToList();

                    if (AreasToAdd.Count > 0) context.ModelosPlantasArea.AddRange(AreasToAdd);//Insert is Ok
                    if (AreasToUpdate.Count > 0) AreasToUpdate.ForEach(x => context.ModelosPlantasArea.Attach(x));//Not working
                    if (AreasToRemove.Count > 0) context.ModelosPlantasArea.RemoveRange(AreasToRemove);//Not tested

                // When saving Model, need to save (add, delete, change) collections. And if a collection fails, the other must not be saved.
                 // So far this Inclusion OK. The change is not working.                

                   this.Update(model);           
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }

            }
```

Update method:

```
public void Update(Modelo item, IEnumerable<string> fieldsToUpdate = null)
{
    base.context.Modelos.Attach(item);

    base.UpdateSave(item, fieldsToUpdate);
}
```

UpdateSave Method:

```
protected void UpdateSave<TEntity>(TEntity item, IEnumerable<string> fieldsToUpdate) where TEntity : class
{
    var entry = this.context.Entry<TEntity>(item);
    if (fieldsToUpdate == null || fieldsToUpdate.Count() == 0)
        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    else
    {
        this.changeFieldsModified<TEntity>(entry, fieldsToUpdate);
    }
    this.Save();
}
```

Save Method:

```
protected void Save(bool auditing = true)
{
    try
    {
        this.context.SaveChanges(auditing);
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException exception)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(exception);
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

SaveChanges Method:

```
public int SaveChanges(bool auditing)
{
    var entriesAdded = new List<DbEntityEntry>();

    // Salva o log dos itens alterados e excluídos.
    if (auditing && base.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
        foreach (var entry in base.ChangeTracker.Entries())
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entriesAdded.Add(entry);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    this.saveEntryOperation(entry, EntityState.Deleted);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    this.saveEntryOperation(entry, EntityState.Modified);
                    break;
            }
    // Realiza a persitência de dados
    int count = base.SaveChanges();

    // Salva o log dos itens adicionados.
    if (auditing && entriesAdded.Count > 0)
        foreach (var entry in entriesAdded)
            this.saveEntryOperation(entry, EntityState.Added);

    this.AuditionContext.SaveChanges();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Attach` merely adds the entity into change tracking, but if you don't actually change it after that point, its state remains `Unchanged`. The fact that it was different from what's in the database already before it was attached is meaningless.

To signal that the entity needs to be updated, you need to set it to `Modified`:

```
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

If the entity is not already attached, this will also have the effect of attaching it, so there's no need to call `Attach` as well.

[EDITED BY Ferreira]
This tip work fine. I made the changes as below.

```
if (ModelosToUpdate.Count > 0)
{
    ModelosToUpdate.ForEach(x => 
    {
        context.ModelosFuncoes.Attach(x);
        var entry = this.context.Entry<ModeloFuncao>(x);
        entry.State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified
    }); 
}
```

Comment: I'll try and I'll post here the result.

Comment: worked fine. Thanks. You saved my day.  One doubt. I need do this to delete too?

Comment: No. Removing from the collection should be enough.